# Complex energies of non-reciprocally coupled chain with hoppings of equal absolute value

Tags: condensed-matter, energy-conservation, hamiltonian, time-evolution, tight-binding

In the Hatano-Nelson chain (i.e. the simplest 1D tight-binding model with nonreciprocal hopping) for positive hoppings $t_{1,2}>0$ you get a purely real spectrum.

However, as soon as you change the sign of one of these hoppings, the spectrum becomes non-real. I understand the maths of it, but how come this is possible physically? After all, if I understand correctly, nothing about nonreciprocity inherently requires an external energy input (for example, thinking about RF gyrators here: they are nonreciprocal and passive components - and I don't think anything conceptually prevents them from being lossless). Negative hopping isn't anything particularly special either, just an extra phase acquired on hopping.
So how come that you get complex energies here, implying that energy is being gained/lost as the associated eigenstates evolve in time?

Edit: To add some explanation: The Hamiltonian of such a chain is just a matrix with (e.g.) 1 on the upper secondary diagonal and -1 on the lower one. This matrix is tridiagonal and skew-symmetric so has purely imaginary eigenvalues which come in pairs of opposite signs.

Comment: Can you cite the paper, where the tight binding model is calculated?

Comment: I don't have a particular paper to cite here, but the model is fairly simple anyway: the Hamiltonian is just a matrix with (e.g.) 1 on the upper second diagonal and -1 on the lower one. This matrix is tridiagonal and skew-symmetric so has purely imaginary eigenvalues which come in pairs of opposite signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to note that there are two different kinds of "non-reciprocal" couplings.

When t1 and t2 have different magnitudes but the same phase you get something similar to an RF gyrator with a real spectrum.

When t1 and t2 have non-reciprocal phases (i.e. not complex conjugates of each other), which includes the case when they have opposite signs, the spectrum becomes complex. I think the easiest way to understand this complex spectrum is to go back to the derivation of the tight binding model from the continuum Schrodinger equation (see e.g. [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.5862)). Microscopically, non-reciprocal hopping phases arise when you have a gain or loss medium between the lattice sites. The relative phase between neighbouring sites determines whether there field interferes constructively or deconstructively in the medium between the sites, affecting the gain or loss rate. Thus, the non-reciprocal phases can be understood as a phase-sensitive loss or gain.